# Constructors and how call works in Javascript

Tags: javascript, object, call

I have a couple of questions about the code.

1) In the student constructor, does **Person.call(this, firstName)** give student access to the methods of person? or does it change the context of **this?**

2)  I assume Student.prototype = Object.create(Person.prototype) gives us acess to the methods and properties of person?

I'm having a hard time understanding the call method.

```
var Person = function(firstName) {
  this.firstName = firstName;
};

Person.prototype.walk = function(){
  console.log("I am walking!");
};


function Student(firstName, subject) {
  Person.call(this, firstName);
  this.subject = subject;
};

Student.prototype = Object.create(Person.prototype); // See note belo
Student.prototype.constructor = Student;

Student.prototype.sayHello = function(){
  console.log("Hello, I'm " + this.firstName + ". I'm studying "
              + this.subject + ".");
};
```

Answer (score 0):

1) No, it sets the `this` value and passes an argument, but as it sets the `this` value of `Person` to whatever `this` is inside `Student`, it could also give `Person` access to  `Student`, but not the other way around.

All `call(this-value, [arg1,arg2])` and `apply(this-value, [[arg1,arg2]])` does, is call the function with a given this-value, and arguments.

2) Yes, `Student.prototype = Object.create(Person.prototype)` copies the prototype of `Person` and sets it as the prototype of `Student`, giving `Student` the same prototyped methods as `Person`, but a copy, not the same reference.

Comment: Thanks adeneo great explanation! I have a couple more questions . If I create  var student1 = new Student("john", "physics");   When the student1 object is created, we invoke the person function passing in 'this' (student1) and the name john . So we have invoked a function outside of the object person1 allowing us to share functions